# Why is Android parsing XML incorrectly?

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I'm writing an Android app for a client of mine that will display his RSS feeds. He has 2 different feeds. One of them works flawlessly with the code I've written using examples. When I replace the URL with his second feed, I get random line breaks everywhere (particularly after an opening bracket < and again before the closing bracket < ).

This is a link to the working feed - http://prgk.ca/wD

Here is the rss feed that doesnt seem to parse correctly using the same code - http://prgk.ca/ps

---

Heres an example from the logcat. You can see that every < and > it also puts a line break for some reason...

```
08-19 09:43:46.444: I/RSSReader(6045): Get the Android App to  know when your advisor is available!
08-19 09:43:46.444: I/RSSReader(6045): http://www.keen.com/CommunityServer/UserBlogPosts/r00tman/Get-the-Android-App-to--know-when-your-
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): advisor-is-available/624194.aspx
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): Thu, 16 Aug 2012 19:39:00 GMT
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): 8ca05964-da1c-4176-9dbc-9d0bc609bb83:624194
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): r00tman
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): 0
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): http://www.keen.com/CommunityServer/blogs/642011/comments/624194.aspx
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): http://www.keen.com/CommunityServer/blogs/642011/commentrss.aspx?PostID=624194
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): http://www.keen.com/CommunityServer/blogs/rsscomments/624194.aspx
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): <
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): a href="http://majesticvision.com/downloads/android/love-tarot.apk"
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): >
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): <
08-19 09:43:46.452: I/RSSReader(6045): img src="http://www.majesticvision.com/keen/2012-08-16_App-Shot.png" height="75" width="385" /
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): >
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): <
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): /a
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): >
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): <
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): br /
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): >
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): <
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): br /
08-19 09:43:46.460: I/RSSReader(6045): >
```

---

Heres a screenshot showing the issue. In this particular one, the URL from the < link >< /link > tag is split in an odd place so part of the URL is missing, and all I am getting from the < description > < /description > tag is just "<" when there should be a whole article

[image: Phone Screenshot]

Comment: Could this `&gt;&lt;` be a problem?

Comment: It will help if you provide an example.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: Both feeds have a lot of HTML embedded in them. The first embeds all the HTML in `<![CDATA[]]>` tags. This seems to work. The second feed encodes all the HTML, so you get a lot of "`&amp;nbsp; &lt;br /&gt;`". Are you decoding the HTML in the second one? And where are you getting the random line breaks?

Comment: Sorry guys, I realize I should have shown an example. Ive added a part of the logcat showing that after every < and > there seems to be a line break

Comment: Without supplying any information regarding how you're parsing it it's impossible to help. android-rss? And how are you attempting to handle the XML after parsing? Log entries are only what a class decides to log--do you actually have issues working with the DOM *after* parsing?

Comment: Which parser as you using?  Each has different ways of handling whitespace, and associated properties and methods to control those ways.  For example, if you're using DOM, then http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#isIgnoringElementContentWhitespace()

Comment: Im using SAX. I followed this tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/section4.html which has all the code (eitherwise I would have to copy and paste 5 different classes to show my code)

Comment: When things don't work like you'd expect, the usual question should be "What am I doing wrong?" and not "Why isn't <whatever platform or language> not working?". The vast majority of "bugs" are between the keyboard and chair. :-)

Comment: While I don't deny the fact that I was doing something wrong, putting "What am I doing wrong" is a pretty un-descriptive and useless title, which would have resulted in an unanswered and likely closed question. The fact that I have Android in the title shows fellow SO users exactly what platform I'm needing help with.

Comment: It's not doing anything incorrectly. You just have incorrect expectations of it. In particular, it's NOT returning line breaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting around this. In my RSSHandler class, i commented out the parts reseting the state

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    String theString = new String(ch, start, length);

    switch (currentstate) {
    case RSS_TITLE:
        _item.setTitle(theString);
        // currentstate = 0;
        break;
    case RSS_LINK:
        _item.setLink(theString);
        // currentstate = 0;
        break;
    case RSS_DESCRIPTION:
        _item.setDescription(theString);
        // currentstate = 0;
        break;
    case RSS_CATEGORY:
        _item.setCategory(theString);
        // currentstate = 0;
        break;
    case RSS_PUBDATE:
        _item.setPubDate(theString);
        // currentstate = 0;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
```

Then in my RSSitem class, i made the string add on to itself instead of just resetting it each time

```
void setDescription(String description) {
    _description = _description + Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
}
```

Its probably not the best fix out there but it ended up working perfectly for me!